# Counting families of subsets of a fixed finite set closed under taking subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

Let's fix a finite set $E, \#E = n$. I am interested in families $\cal S$ of subsets of $E$ with the property that if $A \in {\cal S}$ and $B \subset A$ then $B \in {\cal S}$. My question is: How many such families are there? I'd be happy with a reasonable upper estimate. Bonus if you can estimate the number of such $\cal S$ with fixed $\#{\cal S}$.

(By the way, does this property have a name? It occurs in one possible definition of a matroid but being a matroid is a stronger condition. Do we know how many matroids with a fixed ground set are there?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number

Comment: You are just counting simplicial complexes on $n$ elements...

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks. That answers my main question. What about the bonus question?

Comment: One way to say the number of such $\mathcal{S}$ with $\#\mathcal{S}=k$ is the number of elements of rank $k$ in the free distributive lattice on $n$ elements: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Free_distributive_lattices. Anyways these kinds of questions are well-studied but the numbers become intractable immediately (at least that is my impression)

Comment: For the "bonus question," see the OEIS: http://oeis.org/A269699

Comment: In particular the reference (https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(80)90156-9) shows that for fixed $k$, the number of such $\mathcal{S}$ as a function of $n$ is given by a polynomial in $n$.

Comment: The property is that of a "down-set" or "order ideal" (some simply call them "ideals," but that could be confused with a lattice ideal). See Davey and Priestley or Birkhoff, third edition.

Answer (score 3):

This is Dedekind's Problem.  The best asymptotic estimate is due to Korshunov, but his paper is about 100 pages long. Someone spent almost $2,000 getting it translated to English, but that translation is not publically available.  Sapozhenko's proof seems to be about half as long. I believe some of the papers one might need to understand his proof have also been translated into English and the same person I referred to has those translations.
You can also look at Kleitman and Markowsky.